# Can't filter the Datacenters having servers while provisioning Network Gateway on softlayer

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We can retrieve the datacenters for Network Gateway service from softlayer using below api. 
"https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter/getDatacenters.json"
 It lists all the datacenters but I want those datacenter which will have servers to provision Network Gateway.

Is there any way to filter out those datacenter having servers?

Comment: I`ll provide an answer with a rest call, if it´s not what you require please upload an screenshot of what you need using the portal UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rest api example:

```
https://[apiUsername]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects?objectFilter={"packageType":{"operation":"BARE_METAL_GATEWAY"}}
```

Comment: No problem Sagar, glad to help.